# bash uses only first entry from find

Tags: bash

I'm trying to list all PDF files under a given directory `$1` (and its subdirectories), get the number of pages in each file and calculate two numbers using the pagecount. My script used to work, but only on filenames that don't contain spaces and only in one directory that is only filled with PDF files. I've modified it a bit already (using quotes around variables and such), but now I'm a bit stuck.

The problem I'm having is that, as it is now, the script only processes the first file found by `find . -name '*.pdf'`. How would I go about processing the rest?

```
#!/bin/bash

wd=`pwd`
pppl=0.03 #euro
pppnl=0.033 #eruo

cd $1
for entry in "`find . -name '*.pdf'`"
do
        filename="$(basename "$entry")"
        pagecount=`pdfinfo "$filename" | grep Pages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//'`
        pricel=`echo "$pagecount * $pppl" | bc`
        pricenl=`echo "$pagecount * $pppnl" | bc`
        echo -e "$filename\t\t$pagecount\t$pricel\t$pricenl"
done

cd "$wd"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using find in a for loop, is that if you don't quote the command, the filenames with spaces will be split, and if you do quote the command, then the entire results will be parsed in a single iteration.

The workaround is to use a while loop instead, like this:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' entry
do
    ....
done
```

Read this article for more discussion: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to use word splitting. Use a while loop instead.

```
while read -r entry
do
        filename=$(basename "$entry")
        pagecount=$(pdfinfo "$filename" | grep Pages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//')
        pricel=$(echo "$pagecount * $pppl" | bc)
        pricenl=$(echo "$pagecount * $pppnl" | bc)
        echo -e "$filename\t\t$pagecount\t$pricel\t$pricenl"
done < <(exec find . -name '*.pdf')
```

Also prefer `$()` over `backticks` when possible. You also don't need to place around `""` variables or command substitutions when they are being used for assignment.

```
    filename=$(basename "$entry")
```

As well could simply be just

```
    filename=${entry##*/}
```

Comment: @user000001 It prevents unnecessary additional subprocess. Just something I invented and probably not a known practice to anyone.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on both `exec find` and the difference between `$()` and `backticks` ? I'm reasonably new to all this. Thanks!